# strtok weird behavior on tokenization

Tags: c, string, tokenize, c-strings, strtok

The below code gives unexpected behaviour.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    
    char s[] = "hello $";
    char *t;
    t = strtok(s, "$$");
    printf("%s", t);

    return 0;
}
```

Why does this output `hello` and not `hello $`?

Comment: The function tokenizes using the ***set*** of characters in the second argument, It will use only one of the characters in the second arguyment string.

Comment: The second parameter is a string containing multiple indepent single-character delimiters, not a substring.

Comment: so how should I split by a string?

Comment: "strtok weird behavior" is a truism.  Its weirdness is by design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a comment you wrote:

> so how should I split by a string?

There is no standard way (no predefined library function) for doing this, that I am aware of.

You could write your own split-on-string loop, using `strstr`.  Here is one way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char s[] = "hello$$this$$is$$a$$test";
    char *sep = "$$";
    char *p = s;
    char *p2;
    int i = 1;
    do {
        p2 = strstr(p, sep);
        if(p2 != NULL) *p2 = '\0';
        printf("%d: %s\n", i++, p);
        if(p2 != NULL) p = p2 + strlen(sep);
    } while(p2 != NULL);
}
```

This could be improved, but it works, and it should get you started.

Answer (score 2):

From the C Standard (7.23.5.8 The strtok function)

> 2 A sequence of calls to the strtok function breaks the string pointed
> to by s1 into a sequence of tokens, **each of which is delimited by a
> character from the string pointed to by s2**

In this call

```
t = strtok(s, "$$");
```

the parameter s2 is set as having two identical delimiters. So the call is equivalent to

```
t = strtok(s, "$");
```

If you need to find the substring "$$" in a string you can use the standard C string function `strstr`. For example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char s[] = "hello $";
    
    char *p = strstr( s, "$$" );
    
    if ( p ) *p = '\0';
    
    puts( s );
    
    return 0;
}
```